# Jpa + Hibernate join fetch returning inconsistent data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We are executing via JPA + Hibernate 4 a query which is returning some inconsistent data.

We have one "parent" table:

```
PARENT
    id *
    req_num
    active
    creation_date
```

and one "child" table:

```
CHILD
    id *
    type
    name
    email
```

One parent could have many childs, and this is mapped into database using another table:

```
PARENT_CHILDS
    parent_id (FK to PARENT)
    child_id (FK to CHILD)
    child_order
```

In Java, our Parent class has a @OneToMany annotated List named childs. Both of them are annotated with @Entity.
We're using org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy as our naming strategy.

The query we're executing is:

```
select parent from Parent parent join fetch parent.childs child where child.type IN ('01', '02') and child.email = 'mail@mail.com' and parent.active = 1 and parent.reqNum != 'testReqNum'
```

This is translated to the next plain SQL query (we're seeing this using show_sql=true property):

```
select parent0_.id as id2_, parent0_.active as active2_, parent0_.creation_date as creation2_
    from parent parent0_ 
    inner join parent_childs childs1_ on parent0_.id=childs1_.Application_id 
    inner join child child2_ on childs1_.child_id=child2_.id 
    where (child2_.type in (? , ?)) and child2_.email=? and parent0_.active=? and parent0_.req_num<>?
```

Our parent table has only 2 parents which satisfy the condition "parent0_.active=? and parent0_.req_num<>?". Each of them, has two childs. And only one of their childs satisfies the condition "(child2_.type in (? , ?)) and child2_.email=?".

So, when we execute the SQL query directly to our Oracle database, it returns only 2 rows (the 2 parents with only one child each).

However, in Java we are recovering some weird results, which varies if we use "inner join", "join" or "join fetch". For instance, we're receiving a list of three parents. One with one child, another one with the other child which is not satisfying the mail condition, and a last one with its both childs.

We're wondering why are we experiencing this behaviour, and, more importantly, how could we solve it?

Thanks. Kind regards.

Comment: Please post the resulting SQL using all 3 variants of `inner join`, `join`, and `join fetch`.

Comment: why are you using a join table for a one to many relationship?

Comment: @Naros, all 3 variants result in an identical JPA query, but the "join", "inner join" or "join fetch" (the rest of the query is always the same). And the "translated" SQL is also the same, with an inner join

Comment: @davioooh, that's because when the application was designed it was suposed that a child could belong to more than one parent. We've inherited this model and it can't be changed

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, a many to many relationship is not necessary to implement your solution. Additionally, your link table is not properly a link table because it has its own id, so must be considered as another entity.

If you can't change the DB schema, you could implement relationships among your entities this way:

- a `OneToMany` relationship from `Parent` to `ParentChild`
- a `OneToOne` relationship from `ParentChild` to `Child`

Comment: excuse me, but I made a mistake when I made the question. The parent_childs table has no any id column. It has one "child_order" column which is an extra column with nothing to do in this problem (I have updated my initial post). I agree that this should have been modelled with no relationship table in the midle, but the thing is that we're generating the correct SQL (which is returning the correct rows when executed directly into database). Wouldn't this be caused by any other issue?